# Resetting all values in a column to zero at desired time using Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database, sql-function

I’m working on an app that adds an increment of 1 to an int value, `entries` whenever a user clicks a button. I made use of Postgresql DBMS to store these values. I have done this successfully, however I want all values in the `entries` column of my database table to get reset to 0 at midnight everyday. How do I go about this?
My OS is Windows 10. I have full access on my pc and on my database. I installed postgres by downloading the setup from the official site.

Comment: Use a `cron` job.

Comment: How do I do this? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Depends on information you have not provided: 1) OS? 2) Your access privileges on the machine? 3) Your access privileges to the database? 4) How you installed Postgres? **Add answers as update to question**

Comment: Be specific when referring to a download, in other words point at the site. Assuming you mean [EDB Postgres](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) look at [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.7/pgagent_jobs.html) from the supplied `pgAdmin` GUI.